# Setting up Aamazon EC2 Container Service with existing EC2 and existing docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently have an EC2 running with a docker container, but I was told that naively running it is not good enough and EC2 Container Service can offer a lot more functionalities including auto-restart the docker and keep logging.

I tried to follow the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_GetStarted.html) to set up the EC2 Container Service, but I found the naming conventions is quite confusing.

Can anyone please help me clarify it a bit?

It says

> Retrieve the **docker login** command that you can use to authenticate your Docker client to your registry by pasting the **aws ecr get-login** command from the console into a terminal window.

What is this "console" and "terminal" it refers to?

I tried to run **aws ecr get-login** on both my local cmd that I used to build the docker, and the EC2, both told me that I need to **sudo install** awscli, after I installed it, running **aws ecr get-login** just lead to

```
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
```

Where should I run this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console/terminal is your local command prompt (cmd). Where you run your commands.

After you install the AWS CLI, you need to run `aws configure` to configure your credentials, default region, and default output format.

[Configuring the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)

Once you've got that configured, run `aws ecr get-login` which will return a string of text that is the docker command you will use to sync docker on your machine with your AWS repository. You can just copy and paste the string into your cmd and hit return.

Make sure you set your region correctly and make sure you choose the desired output. You can always override the region or the output when running `aws` commands by using `--region desiredregion` or `--output json|text`.

Examples:

- `aws ecr describe-repositories --region us-west-1 --output text`
- `aws ecr describe-repositories --region us-west-1 --output json`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I later found out that the main problem is that I should not use `sudo apt-get install` to install awscli. The apt-get version is too old so it does not recognize the command. `pip install` rescues me.